# OL3: GetFeature from Layers by Coordinate

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I want to get the Feature of a Layer by coordinate.
Furthermore I want to open this feature in a popup, which I have solved so far by an onclick event. But I want to realize by giving the coordinates of a feature and opening the popup of the featue.

I have a layer with the map and a layer with the features:

```
if (trackMap != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < trackMap.length; i++) {
    var trackInfo = trackMap[i];
    lat = parseFloat(trackInfo.lat);
    lon = parseFloat(trackInfo.lon);

    var layergpx = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        parser: new ol.parser.GPX(),
        url: '${contextRoot}/gps/gpx2' + trackInfo.url
      })
    });
    layers.push(layergpx);
  }
}
```

I want to get the feature of this layer in another Javascript function.

How I open a pop up by clicking on the map:

```
/**
 * The Click Event to show the data
 */
var element = document.getElementById('popup');
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
      element: element,
      positioning: ol.OverlayPositioning.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      stopEvent: false
});
map.addOverlay(popup);

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  map.getFeatures({
    pixel: evt.getPixel(),
    layers: vectorLayers,
    success: function(layerFeatures) {
      var feature = layerFeatures[0][0];
      if (feature) {
        var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
        var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
        popup.setPosition(coord);
        $(element).popover({
          'placement': 'top',
          'html': true,
          'content': feature.get('desc')
        });
        $(element).popover('show');
      } else {
        $(element).popover('destroy');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

But I want this feature not to be opened by clicking on it on the map, but by entering a coordinate in a textfield and the map opens this pop up, like in the onclick event.

Comment: From what understood you want to get a feature from this layergpx layer, right?
Why, don't you want to create the popup from the callback function of the selection? You can use any JS function as a callback.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this example to see if it helps you:
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml.html

```
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
  map.getFeatures({
    pixel: pixel,
    layers: [vector],
    success: function(featuresByLayer) {
      var features = featuresByLayer[0];
      var info = [];
      for (var i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        info.push(features[i].get('name'));
      }
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = info.join(', ') || '&nbsp';
    }
  });
```

map.getFeatures() has this success callback where it delivers the features of the layers specified in layers: [vector]. Customize it at will to get what you need.

=== Update ===

In the OpenLayers 3's Map object you have a function: getPixelFromCoordinate

```
/**
 * @param {ol.Coordinate} coordinate Coordinate.
 * @return {ol.Pixel} Pixel.
 */
ol.Map.prototype.getPixelFromCoordinate = function(coordinate) {
  var frameState = this.frameState_;
  if (goog.isNull(frameState)) {
    return null;
  } else {
    var vec2 = coordinate.slice(0, 2);
    return ol.vec.Mat4.multVec2(frameState.coordinateToPixelMatrix, vec2, vec2);
  }
};
```

Comment: I think, I already implemented what you are suggesting, I just didn't post it. Sorry for that. The problem is, I don't know the pixel of the feature, but I know the coordinate of the feature.
I want to open the pop up, like on the onclick event, but by entering the coordinates.

Comment: You could add a Vector layer where you add a feature (Point) and then get the pixel of that point (feature).

Comment: look at my Update, you can discard my previous comment. Just pass in the coordinate and you will get the Pixel.

Comment: And how do I call this function?
I tried:
`ol.Map.prototype.getPixelFormCoordinate(ol.proj.transform([doubleLon, doubleLat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))`
and `map.getPixelFormCoordinate(ol.proj.transform([doubleLon, doubleLat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))` 
But I am a bit stuck or confused? :-/

Comment: just use it in the map object. 
myMap = new ol.Map(...); pixel=myMap.getPixelFormCoordinate(ol.proj....)

Comment: What ol.js do you use? My Openlayers does not have a function `getPixelfromCoordinate`, and if I add the function, the variable `goog`, `ol.vec.Mat4.multVec2` are unknown

Comment: From the source: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/map.js
Quick question, are you using ol3 in a production environment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44889/discussion-between-donmarco-and-rui-lima)

Comment: Sorry can't access to chat overhere.

Comment: Yes, I am using this in production environment. Originally just for testing, but since everything worked we needed, mostly even better than in ol2, we used if for production already..
Which brings me to the problem of how to customize this OL3... I did not get this "goog" thing...

Comment: I don't know if it is good idea to use this in prod env, it can change and having you to also change a lot of your code - risky!. 
goog is related to closure (https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial)

Comment: It's beta. I know it and that its not perfect, but everything I need works. And as long as I don't work on their script, but on my own, they can't change anything in my production.
Ok, so there is no way, to get around CLOSURE to get a full ol3.js?

Comment: I would say no. You have to stick with it.